# How to change the name of the document in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a Macro Enabled Template called TIP-PBI.xltm. When I create a document based on this template, Excel automatically names it TIP-PBI1. However, I want to give it a custom name.

I figured I could do that by modifying the .Title property of the Workbook. To that end, on startup the Workbook_Open event kicks off, and the following is executed:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim strPBI As String
    strPBI = InputBox$("Enter PBI", "Enter PBI")

    ThisWorkbook.Title = "TIP-PBI-" & strPBI
End Sub
```

However, this does nothing.

How can I change the Title of the document on startup?

Comment: i think your only option to change the name from within the WB is to save it so something like `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "" & Target.Text & ".xls"`

Comment: @TomIngram You're right: make it an answer. When starting a new document from a template, all the Office apps give the new (unsaved) file the template name with a sequential number on the end. The only way to change that is to save it with a new name.

Comment: @TomIngram How would I override the user pressing the Save button?  I don't need to save it on startup, just need to change the document title, so that when the user clicks `Save`, my custom name is the suggested name of the file.

Answer (score 6):

the only way to change the workbook name is to save it ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb210376(v=office.12).aspx)) so you could do something like

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "" & FileName & ".xls"
```

if you only want to suggest a name then you could use [GetSaveAsFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195748(v=office.11).aspx) or

```
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "" & FileName & ".xls"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the new workbook is created from a template then it takes the template name.  Hence in instances where I wish to set the name of the new work book I copy a dummy template to the required name and then open the new workbook based upon the renamed template.

```
 strFile = "C:\Temp\" & strnewname & ".xltx "

 FileCopy "C:\Temp\Dummy.xltx", strFile

 'Open template to new workbook

 Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFile

 Kill strFile  'delete renamed template
```